# How to prevent multiple accounts with social media login?

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus-signin

Next to a regular username/email/password system I want to have social media buttons for signing in. But how do I prevent users from creating multiple accounts?

Let's say someone logs into my app through `Facebook` first and does things in the app that get stored in the database attached to this account. A view weeks later he want to look it up again but presses the `Google+` sign in button and now it appears he lost all his data since this account is not "linked".

- I could create an option for the user to link there accounts but how do I verify this? Besides that I have to merge all data in the database.
- Perhaps the API's have build in functionality for this?
- Is there somekind of social media library that handles this?

Comment: Is user's email id same for all the social network accounts?

Comment: @Pr38y No, someone could have a different email for twitter then for facebook.

Comment: Yes! One simple approach is after logging in by social login, ask them to create another ID (use their existing email maybe) associated with the account. Just like Line (a chat app) one ID can have multiple social login account.

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung It's a nice work around but it still requires an extra requirement from the user which I would like to keep to a minimum. I already thought of creating a guest account first, then ask the player if he would like to remain using the app he has to fill in his email so he could retrieve his account. Then the social media linking would show up and it is only possible to login with these accounts, not register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If user is using same email id, user id can be mapped one-to-one to email id. When user login through facebook - facebook auth-token  can be updated in DB. Separate column will be required for all the social login app, user is allowed to login from.

In case of different email-id, explicit connect from other network button can be used.

Another option is to use device id instead of email id, but then login will be specific to that device only. That may give issue to sync data from different phone.

Comment: I guess mapping them all to the same email would be the proper way. I'll just ask the email from the user first if he would like his data to be saved. After that present options of linking his account with social media.

Comment: For saving data first email id can be taken as default. If user link using other email-id, you can ask for save-account preference. It will reduce user interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Well i don't know an appropriate answer but i can give a work around, add a field in the database call it "loginway" lets say and then when the user login via facebook, you fill the field with 1, google+ 2 ... etc when the user press a social button login the application go check the field if the login is different from the original one promote him, that you already logged in with facebook, please use the facebook login again.

user login first time -> loginway field filled with 1 -> logs in
user login the second time using G+ -> App checks loginway -> it's different from the old one -> user get a message box please login via the first method(facebook).

i hope that i helped you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

In your Profile setting you need to give option for adding other accounts.
For example if user logins with Facebook and you have Google as other option then in setting, there should be option to add Google account for user. So that user can link all accounts and then can login from every social network account. You need to store all accounts in backend and need to manage all.

Comment: But the question is how to prevent the user from registering 2 accounts when he first registers with one, does not link it and then registers with another.